# Asserting Junit output not working

Tags: java, junit

I have a method (par.getstatus) which outputs a message that looks exactly like this:
3::0::P:3::C:2::S:1::M:1::D:0::A:0::Q:0null

problem is when I write:

```
    String s = par.getStatus(3);
    assertTrue(s == "3::0::P:3::C:2::S:1::M:1::D:0::A:0::Q:0null");
```

it does not return true. I know that the string is the right one, cause I printed it to the console, and copied and pasted it directly, checked that I did that right many times. And to check that it is not the assertTrue method that I am using that is wrong, I wrote:

```
    String d = "rr";
            assertTrue(s == "rr");
```

which returns true.

Someone said that it could be null that is causing the problems, so i removed that, but still no luck. Does anyone know what the problem could be here? thanks

Comment: Please search for answers on SO... You should never compare strings (or, indeed, most objects) in java using the == comparison operator.  Use `aString.compareTo(otherString)` or `aString.equals(otherString)`.

Comment: thanks I did search but missed the other thread, will look harder next time. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
s == "3::0::P:3::C:2::S:1::M:1::D:0::A:0::Q:0null"
```

`==` compares the references of two Strings and these two strings are not the same Object.

use `String.equals()` to compare the content of two Strings: Have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

```
assertTrue(s.equals("3::0::P:3::C:2::S:1::M:1::D:0::A:0::Q:0null"));
```